# How to debug remotely a nodeJs app inside Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

I have a simple nodeJs app which is uses express frame work. I can successfully run this app inside a docker container.

I need to debug this app remotely from VS code how to do that.

the following steps I took to debug remotely inside a

### simple node app.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var fs = require('fs')
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt', { flags: 'a'  })

app.get('/', function(reg, res){

    res.send('Home page ' + reg.params.id);
});

app.get('/:id', function(reg, res){

    if(reg.params.id != 'favicon.ico')
        logger.write( ' ' + reg.params.id);

    res.send('Home page ' + reg.params.id);
});


app.listen(3000, function(){

    console.log('A test server is running');
})
```

### VScode launch.json

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Process",
    "port": 5858,
    "address": "192.168.1.10",
    "restart": false,
    "sourceMaps": false,
    "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
    "remoteRoot": "/app/"
 }
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.2.0-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
WORKDIR /app/src
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5858
CMD ["node","--debug-brk=5858","app.js"]
```

**docker build command**

```
docker build -t remotedebug .
```

**docker run command**

```
docker run --rm --name test -p8080:3000 -p5858:5858 remotedebug
```

after running the docker it console outputs a message

> Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858

but I cant access the node app from localhost:8080 and cannot debug from VScode.

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk` for your dockerfile cmd, remember to specfiy `0.0.0.0` as nodejs bind to `127.0.0.1` that would cause the problem.

example:

```
expose 9090
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9090 ...otherargs
```

and vscode:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "attach to docker",
  "port": 9290
  "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app/server"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using native docker or docker-machine? I suspect you're using docker machine in which case docker is running inside a virtual machine and you need to connect to the IP address of that machine rather than `127.0.0.1`. Type:

```
docker-machine ls
```

And you'll get an output like this:

```
NAME ACTIVE DRIVER STATE URL SWARM DOCKER ERRORS 
default - virtualbox Running tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 v1.9.1
```

In this case you'd tell VS Code to connect to 192.168.99.100:5858

Comment: I have separate linux computer with docker installed, I am accessing it from my local network. There no virtual machine. when I execute `node app.js' in docker file then I can access my app through `ipaddress:8080` and when I execute `node app.js --debug-brk=5858 app.js` I cant access the app

Comment: Which version of which distro are you running? It's likely that the local firewall is preventing access to port 5858 and 8080.

Comment: `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial`

Comment: Can you run `sudo ufw status numbered`  and post the output please?

Comment: `status: inactive`

Comment: Hmm - odd. I've just noticed that you're exposing port 8080 and not 3000 from your Dockerfile. If you change `EXPOSE 8080` to `EXPOSE 3000` can you connect to the node app on 8080?

Comment: still cannot debug this is the message in my VScode `Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js version could not be determined (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.10:5858)`

Comment: But you can connect to the app from a browser? Can you run `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` - this will tell us if 5858 is open or not.

Comment: No, I cant connect the app from browser when I run node app with debug mode in docker container. In my linux computer neither 8080 nor 5858 ports  are listed for `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` where I run docker